# Deleting own answer

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Can you tell me if there is a case in which users can delete their own answer when it has been *accepted*? Is there a limit of upvotes or what?

If there is an exception, can you tell me what is the correct procedure?

Comment: They can't as the answer is useful. You could ask to be disassociated with the answer by flagging it with a custom flag.

Comment: @RobertLongson, who decides  if it is useful, not its owner?

Comment: The accepter decided it was useful by accepting it.

Comment: @RobertLongson, Thanks, only OP can authorize its deletion, or any mod can take a decision?

Comment: mods can but are unlikely to delete accepted answers; their role is not to delete useful content, the OP can only unaccept and maybe cast a single delete vote which would not by itself delete the answer.

Comment: If you need to delete an accepted answer, you could comment to the OP and ask them nicely if they would remove the "accepted" so you can delete the answer. But I would not do this unless there is another answer to the question, as you are breaking a (potentially) good Q&A pair otherwise

Answer (score 6):

You can't delete your answer if it has been accepted.

Moderators can delete it, but are unlikely to do so. The only exception would be if the answer were considered to be spam or offensive for some reason.

If you want to remove the answer then you must persuade the questioner to unaccept it.

What you **shouldn't** do is vandalise your answer by editing the content out. This will be noted and rolled back. If you persist in the vandalism the answer will be locked and your account may well be suspended.

Comment: This is right, after the scope of [health.se] changed, a number of mine (inclduing 2 accepted) were removed. I deleted a number, but couldn't remove the accepted ones.

Answer (score 4):

When you answer a question, you do that to help the one posting the question.

When the OP accepts your answer it becomes a little from him or her. It is the solution to his/her problem and it should remain there. You can't delete it, only when the OP unaccepts your answer you can.

There is not so much you can do about it. In extreme cases you might want to flag it and ask a moderator to disassociate your answer. It remains there, but your name isn't on it any more.

I would to reevaluate if it really should be deleted and if so, flag it.